# PHP cURL - "Illegal characters found in URL1" when using varibles

Tags: php, php-curl

So I'm sending a cURL request to a website with some content and it works fine, but if I use a variable, where I've got some info from a MySQL-DB, in the string, it returns with the error "ERROR: Illegal characters found in URL1".

I've tried to use the variable like `$var`, `(string) $var` and `"{$var}"`, but none of these worked

This is what I have

```
//Up here, some code where I get some data from the database

$apiKey = "...";
$name = $userinfo["Name"];
$number = "...";

$content = "Hey " . $name;

$str = str_replace(array(" ", "/n"), array("+", "%0A"), $content);

$url = "https://thing.thing.com/thing/http/send?apiKey=" . $apiKey . "&to=45" . $number . "&content=" . $str;

//Down here I send the cURL request
```

If I use another self-declared variable like `$name = "Albert Einstein"`, it works fine.

When I just return the `$name` variable, I get the output as a string like `Random name`.

So why is it that I get an error when using a variable I've got from DB. And how can I fix it?

Hope you understand my problem and can help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to encode your strings using [urlencode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php) before using them in the URL.

```
$apiKey = urlencode("...");
$name   = urlencode($userinfo["Name"]);
$number = urlencode("...");
```

The function encodes illegal URL characters so they safely can be used in URLs.
Example: `Random name` becomes `Random%20name`